# how to point a domain folder to a subdomain?

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel, apache, dns

Domain: **www.example.com** (PHP laravel site)

Subdomain: **one.example.com** (Wordpress site)

I need to create **www.example.com/one** with the content of **one.example.com**.
We have currently a simple Laravel  routing/redirect from **www.example.com/one** to **one.example.com** but we need our WordPress site working on **www.example.com/one**

how to point a domain folder to a subdomain?

I do not know if a should use DNS records, httpdaccess file, etc..

Comment: if you have cpanel details then you can do that easily by sudomain section of cpanel.

Comment: Either the configuration file, or htaccess, with a RewriteRule will do fine.

Comment: With htaccess: RedirectMatch 301 ^/one/$ http://one.example.com

Comment: ^ You might wanna try with a 302 first, in case it doesn't work and your cache server cached the 301. Been there, done that.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using ubuntu server you can configure virtual host though apache.
Please follow this link
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts